# Azure ADB2C in to the react native mobile application using expo cli - in login facing File or directory not found error

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I like to develop react native mobile application using expo cli. regarding that i  integrate authenticate using azure adb2c.

I configured Like this
https://github.com/GSingh01/ad-b2c-react-native

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwJei.jpg)

COnfiguration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWQRn.jpg)

Comment: please refer to https://github.com/GSingh01/ad-b2c-react-native

Comment: @JimXu In Azure Portal , I had look at this url and want to know how to configure below things in azure portal <LoginView
        appId="myAppId"
        redirectURI="myRedirectURI"
        tenant="myTenant"
        loginPolicy="B2C_1_SignUpSignIn"
        passwordResetPolicy="B2C_1_PasswordReset"
        profileEditPolicy="B2C_1_ProfileEdit"
        onSuccess={this.onLogin}
        onFail={this.onFail}
        secureStore={MySecureStore}
        renderLoading={this.spinner}
        scope="openid offline_access myScope1 myScope2 ...." //optional, but see the notes above
      />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered application Azure AD B2C. refer to the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-native-application?tabs=app-reg-ga

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows

then configured in sign in policy name, redirect URI(https://jwt.ms), application id in login view. it works.